# Compare Table experts needed!

Tags: einstein-analytics, datatable, charts, einstein, graph

**Description:**

I have a table like below, the Price Change row which contains '300' for 2018 and '600' for 2019 is the sum of values of all products per year.

Price Change is a column defined by the formula P2-P1.

[image: Compare Table on Price Changes over Year per Product]

**Problem:**

I want to transform the compare table above into a chart which is presented below.

[image: Price Change Chart]

**Question:**

Which type of calculations should I carry out, to make it happen. I couldn't really make use of the functions. I hope compare table experts can shed some light on it.

[image: Calculation and Formulas]

Comment: You may want to post to the [Einstein Analytics trailblazer group](https://success.salesforce.com/featuredGroupDetail?id=a1z30000006IDYqAAO) also.

Comment: Hey David,  actually I already posted here as well https://sforce.co/2MNQihq thanks anyway.